# How to force Excel process to quit after COM automation?

Tags: php, excel, com

In PHP I create an XLS-file using COM-object.

```
$excel = new COM("Excel.Application") or die("Excel is not installed!");
$excel->WorkBooks->Add();
...
$excel->WorkBooks[1]->SaveAs($path);
$excel->Quit();
$excel->Release();
$excel = null;
```

After this code has been run, Excel.exe process still be in memory for ~ 6 minutes. How to force this process to quit immediately?

Answer (score 3):

You are using COM objects, so you must be talking about php on Windows. Basically, you can kill tasks using the command line tool [taskkill](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true). You can call that using the php command shell_exec, like

```
shell_exec('taskkill /F /IM "excel.exe"');
```

If you don't have the rights (but I believe you should because you started this process), run the cmd line using [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true).

BUT! You are using php, so if you are running this in a web environment and people are accessing your website simultaneously, you might have multiple instances of Excel running. If that is the case, you'd have to figure out which one you want to kill.

Answer (score 0):

The process sticks around for some time in case another "Excel.Application" object is requested, in which case we can avoid the cost of starting a new process and loading all the DLLs.

I'd just see it as a feature.

Comment: hmm, but on other server with same _Windows 2008 Server R2_ and _Excel 2003_ process terminates immediately.

Comment: As I know, Windows doesn't unload executable for some time after execution ends, but process becomes invisible in Task Manager. In my case Excel.exe process stays visible in Task Manager. And when I run PHP code again, system creates new process.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way...
Try Uninitializing COMS. Instead of doing it just once, do it 4 times. This was established through trial and error so I do not have a valid reason for it except that it works. However, this does not work all the time. It might just work in your case

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.